# Am I better off using Google Mail servers to ensure my email isn't marked as spam?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, mx-record

I'm starting an E-Card business.  And although mine is completely legitimite, I know they can be frequently flagged as spam.

These are for people's birthdays and such, and it is important that they have the best chance of reaching the recipient.

Am I better off using Google mx servers for my mail?  Or is there a service that could help with this?  My host is in good standing with the big guys, but they are getting bigger and bigger each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend using Google's servers. I would instead recommend you use some sort of mail sending service ([Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) and [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) come to mind).

If you send via Google you will have the following problems:

- The "From" header will be forced to be your google account
- You are limited to only 200 a day
- If they think you are sending too many, they will just cut you off.

I can vouch for PostMark. I have used them and have nothing but great things to say about them.

Comment: the "From" can be your sites domain if you pay for GMail. (I believe, I could be wrong)

Comment: @Walter - Yes, it can be, but its still annoying that the card will say "From: eCard Website" rather than the actual sender's name

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice!

Comment: Postmark looks absolutely perfect.  I just signed up.  Exactly what I needed...

Comment: @adam - Yea, it is excellent. I recommend it 100%

Answer (score 1):

I use Google Apps - free - as my professional mail provider, and have been satisfied so far.
This is the header of a test mail I sent to another account (not on Google) :

```
Return-Path: <john.smith@mydomain.com>
X-Original-To: friend@todomain.com
Delivered-To: john@com
Received: from mail-iw0-f175.google.com (mail-iw0-f175.google.com [209.85.214.175])
by mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id BF569020E12
for <friend@todomain.com>; Wed, 29 Sep 2010 12:24:36
Received: by iwn2 with SMTP id 2so642875izn.32
    for <friend@todomain.com>; Tue, 28 Sep 2010 20:24:34
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.231.33.137 with SMTP id h9zr1025957ibd.91.1285730674654;
Received: by 10.231.193.8 with HTTP;
X-Originating-IP: [72.14.240.41]
Date: Wed, 29 Sep 2010 12:24:34
Message-ID: <AANLkTi=z6F+zndcDd+BDb72vg-XfQMvv=AjUy2-=G66P@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: John Smith <john.smith@mydomain.com>
To: friend@todomain.com
```

I changed my own data (domain and names) with a search replace, in order to keep the original structure.
The `From` is intact, and besides the Google servers, there is no much trace of a google account. I.e. unless the recipient looks at the message *source*, she will not notice it comes from Google.

I use the *free* Google Apps subscription.

I would recommend to use the Google Apps mail. It requires a credit-card at first, but you can then cancel the subscription or keep it to have more space / advantages.
I guess this is a way for Google to have an *identity* proof, which a spammer would be unlikely to give.

Again, very satisfied so far. I would recommend you to visit the Google page [here](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html), in order to assess if the conditions fit your requirements, and decide if you need the *free* or the *paid* membership.

Comment: Thanks ring0!  Think its better that I avoid for now.  But glad to know the option is there.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Google for this purpose.

Perhaps if you use DomainKeys and DKIM in each e-mail, it will make the message appear less spammy. It would be worth a shot to look into it I think.

Comment: Looking into it now.  Thanks emostar.